# Missing article in this construction involving an uncountable noun

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8e9HYsInAw&list=UUE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw#t=60) YouTube video from 1:00 to 1:06 the following sentence is said:

> I can take anything that inspires me and make it part of our music.

Should there be the indefinite article *a* before *part*? Is it missing because *music* itself is uncountable? That doesn't make much sense because music can have many parts to it, so it seems that the indefinite article *a* is necessary.

Comment: Part of me is contemplating an answer now... As [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/part) shows, _part_ does not always have to have an article. I don't think it depends on whether the following noun is countable or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between *part* and *a part* has to do with the context and intent of the sentence, not the noun that the *part* is referencing.

According to [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/part), the two most common definitions of part are:

> 1. An amount or section which, when combined with others, makes up the whole of something:
>      *'divide the circle into three equal parts'*
> 2. Some but not all of something:
>      *'the painting tells only part of the story'*
>      <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries Online, "part"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/part)</sub>

Definition 1 comes off as more segmented and distinct than definition 2. Imagine definition 1 as talking about slices of a pie, and definition 2 as talking about ingredients mixed into a cake. Both are *parts*, but one is separable, the other is not.

**When you say something is *a part* something, you are using definition 1**. So to make something *a part of our music* means that we want to incorporate that specific element (dubstep wobble, or cowbell, for instance) into our music.

**When you say something is *part* of something, you're using definition 2**. So to make something *part of our music* means that we want to make it integral to our music, an inseparable defining element.

Hope this helps!